# No database adapter was found in the static registry

Tags: php, zend-framework2

For the first time faced with such a problem... When trying to get a static adapter in the zf2:

```
$this->adapter = \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter();
```

...for example in the constructor of my plugin I receive an error:

```
No database adapter was found in the static registry.
```

My global config file looks like:

```
<?php
//config/global.php

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'            => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'               => 'mysql:dbname=example-db;host=localhost',
        'driver_options'    => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES "UTF8"'
        ),
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
      'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($serviceManager) {
            $adapterFactory = new Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory();
               $adapter = $adapterFactory->createService($serviceManager);
               // set static adapter
               \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);

               return $adapter;
         }
      ),
   ),
);
```

Who knows what could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you register a factory with the service manager you have to request it before it will create the instance. This is a big change from Zend 1 where they had singletons for major components like the db adapter. The advantage of this approach is scalability, which is where Zend 1 stumbled.

You can fetch the adapter anywhere you can access the service locator. For example in the controller you can do something like this:

```
$sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
$adapter = $sl->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem have been resolved as follows:

```
    // module/Application/Module.php
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
         $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
         $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
\Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);
    }
```

I think that there's the best way to integrate the static adapter in application which allows get it easily in the future.